# FXMLLoader works when I run code inside Intellij IDEA but not after building artifacts

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar, filenotfoundexception, fxmlloader

I have this excetpion only when I run program as a jar. I spent few hours trying to fix this issue but without success.

I already tried to find solution online and you are my last chance to fix this.

I would appreciate any kind of your help.

[This is my project structure and code snipet where first exception occured.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4k2Yd.png)

```
C:\Users\Gerrix\Desktop>java -jar Provera.jar
    Initialize...
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: count_number.xml (The system cannot find the file specified)
            at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
            at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
            at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
            at sample.Controller.countLimit(Controller.java:309)
            at sample.Controller.timer(Controller.java:213)
            at sample.Controller.initialize(Controller.java:120)
            at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)
            at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
            at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2409)
            at sample.Main.showPersonOverview(Main.java:60)
            at sample.Main.start(Main.java:42)
            at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
            at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
            at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
            at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
            at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
            at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: auth.xml (The system cannot find the file specified)
            at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
            at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
            at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
            at sample.TwitterService.initialize(TwitterService.java:49)
            at sample.TwitterService.<init>(TwitterService.java:33)
            at sample.Controller.lambda$initialize$0(Controller.java:111)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    javafx.fxml.LoadException:
    file:/C:/Users/Gerrix/Desktop/Provera.jar!/sample/sample.fxml

            at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
            at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2579)
            at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
            at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2409)
            at sample.Main.showPersonOverview(Main.java:60)
            at sample.Main.start(Main.java:42)
            at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
            at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
            at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
            at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
            at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
            at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at sample.Controller.countLimit(Controller.java:316)
            at sample.Controller.timer(Controller.java:213)
            at sample.Controller.initialize(Controller.java:120)
            at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)
            ... 13 more
    Exception in thread "Thread-5" java.lang.NullPointerException
            at sample.TwitterService.initialize(TwitterService.java:57)
            at sample.TwitterService.<init>(TwitterService.java:33)
            at sample.Controller.lambda$initialize$0(Controller.java:111)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Where is the file you are trying to read stored? Is it really a single file on your file system, or is it possible that it resides inside of your `.jar` file? If it does so, you should look into `Controller.class.getResourceAsStream("/count_number.xml")` to get an `InputStream` for the given "file" (note the `/` at the beginning of the string. This specifies that the content you are trying to read is in the root of you classpath, i.e. in the root of you `.jar` file). `FileInputStream` can only read from actual files.

Comment: I have just extracted my .jar file and "count_number.xml" is not inside. But I dont know how to finde where is "count_number.xml" stored, somewhere outside of my .jar file. :(

Comment: how exactly are you creating the `jar`?

Comment: Project Structure -> Artifacts -> Add -> JAR -> From module with dipendencies -> Select main class -> Ok 
And than Build -> Build artifacsts